# Why does my bootstrap nav bar italicize instead of adding the active class to the active tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap nav bar adds a span and italicizes the active tab instead of just adding the active class to the active tab. My code is as follows:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="#">Wutup?!</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse">
      <wicket:link>
            <ul class="nav">
              <li><a href="NearbyEvents.html">Nearby Events</a></li>
              <li><a href="Index.html">My Events</a></li>
              <li><a href="ManageEvents.html">Manage My Events</a></li>
              <li><a href="AboutPage.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </wicket:link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The behavior can be seen here: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4jVC.png)

Comment: the live site is [here](http://wutup.cs.lmu.edu/NearbyEvents)

Comment: it's in the source.. problem is in your markup generation. Also some invalid xml markup in source `<wicket>`

Comment: So, bootstrap doesn't play nice with apache wicket? This is frustrating, but C'est La Vie.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the wicket auto-link feauture (i.e. wicket:link) it generates span instead of adding class to your HTML. For example if "My evenets" was the active page, the could would look like this:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="NearbyEvents.html">Nearby Events</a></li>
    <li><span><em>My Events</em></span></li>
    <li><a href="ManageEvents.html">Manage My Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="AboutPage.html">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you want to avoid that, you should not use the autolinking feauture, or just change the css to suits the wicket's html that is generated.